# Formik - FieldArray with radio input

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, next.js, formik

I'm using `formik 1.5.8` the version right before version 2, and I'm trying to use `<FieldArray />` to generate multiple nested choices for the user (questions and MCQ answers).

Everything works great, but the thing is I want to generate a `radio button` input with each answer to flag this answer as the correct one.

The nested `<FieldArray />` generating fine, but as you know in order to make the `Radio Button` work, you have to give them all the same name with different values, so in this scenario, I'm giving them the name of the first answer option, so when I change them only the first answer option changes its value.

How can I do such a thing where the selected radio button changes its correct field value to `true` and the others to `false`?

Here's a `Codesandbox` to demonstarate ...

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-yup-fieldarray-with-radio-inputs-r5yxl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone would like to show us how to do this using `Radibuttons` please go ahead and I'll accept your answer as the correct one.

But for those of you who are interested, I managed to solve this by using something other than a "radio" buttons to set the value of the "correct answer" flag, I simply used a button to set the value of the correct form value to `true` and in the same time set the value of the other related inputs to `false`.

here's the button I used ...

```
<button
    type="button"
    className={ values.payload[index].answers[index2].correct
            ? "active"
            : ""}
    onClick={() => {
        values.payload[index].answers.map(
            (tem3, index3) => {
                setFieldValue(`payload[${index}].answers[${index3}].correct`,false);
            }
        );
        setFieldValue(flagName, true);
    }}
>
    {values.payload[index].answers[index2].correct
        ? "Correct Answer"
        : "Mark As Correct"
    }
</button>
```

I also updated the `Codesandbox` example here ...

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-yup-fieldarray-with-buttons-instead-of-radio-inputs-0ek59